# Github API to upload images

Tags: github-api

how to add image to GitHub using **GitHub API** ?

( using GitHub API to remotely upload the images )

i tried the code below and it is working absolutely fine

```
url = new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{file-name}" );
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer {access token}");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
String body = "{\n" +
      "  \"message\": \"" + "myFirstImage" + "\",\n" +
      "  \"content\": \"" + encodedImage + "\"\n" +
      "}";

 connection.setDoOutput(true);
 connection.getOutputStream().write(body.getBytes());
```

but the url to access this images is = **"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{owner}/{repo}/main/{file-name}"**

and the link is blocked in my country...( able to access it through vpn )

the images will be accessed by random users on my platform ( user-base is limited to my country )
..so cannot implement loading through VPN

so is there an alternative way to retrieve this image ( maybe some other url storing the same image ) or a way to upload the image using **GitHub API** so that it can be accessed through the link **"https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/****.jpeg"**

Comment: Can I ask WHY the power that be blocked it? This is crazy: https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/gadgets-news/github-content-domain-blocked-for-these-indian-users-reports/articleshow/96687992.cms

Comment: please have a look at this, they say you can sort of re-route your contents on the main //github.com/ domain enabling GH-Pages on your repo: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/42655#discussioncomment-5669289

Comment: @GrafiCode I appreciate your help , solved my problem :-)